# Torrent client that saves files to torrent location

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

I currently use Flexget to download torrent files from an rss feed. Flexget automatically saves each torrent in its subfolder, according to a set of rules and names it accordingly.

Now, what I want is have a torrent client where I can set it up so that when I doubleclick on a torrent, it removes the torrent and simply downloads the linked file to the *location of the torrent file*.

On a Mac I could do this with [Transmission](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lrojgvKRH01qiaydk.png) but most of the torrent clients in Linux that I've tested so far resort to a "general download folder" which is more than useless to me as it messes up my carefully constructed path and makes me do the "hard chore" of moving each file to its original location after download.

I've looked into Transmission json file and couldn't find this option, so does anybody knows how can I set it up on Transmission or any other client that does this "trick" of downloading to where the original torrent file was?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `deluge` for that purpose

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

it should work like charm (i call it as utorrent of linux, they are very similar)

Comment: For this to be an answer you should explain how to do this.

Comment: i0ve tried deluge, didn't found no option to download file to torrent location. could you elaborate where that option is or how to set it up?